# Jetstack Cert not able to challenge

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, lets-encrypt

Not sure why but I am unable to get cert, I clearly misconfigured something but I am not sure what. Any help would be appreciated. If it matters, I own the domain and currently have it routing to a GCP Load balancer (without a backend).  I am using GKE and attempting to build my terraform scripts for the entire environment.

Error from cert-manager logs:
E0622 05:13:10.463096 1 controller.go:185] orders controller: Re-queuing item "default/ambassador-certs-3303005432" due to error processing: Error constructing Challenge resource for Authorization: ACME server does not allow selected challenge type or no provider is configured for domain ".net"

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: <MYEMAIL>
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: ambassador-certs
    dns01:
      providers:
      - name: letsencrypt-prod
        clouddns:
          # The ID of the GCP project
          project: <MYPROJECTID>
          # This is the secret used to access the service account
          serviceAccountSecretRef:
            name: cert-manager-credentials
            key: gcp-dns-admin.json
```

Certificate:

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: ambassador-certs
spec:
  secretName: ambassador-certs
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: "<mydomain>.net"
  dnsNames:
  # you can add multiple domains here
  - "<mydomain>.net"
  acme:
    config:
    - dns01:
        provider: cloud-dns
      domains:
      # you can add multiple domains here
      - "<mydomain>.net"
```

Comment: issuer is namespace specified. Are the issuer and certificate in the same namespace?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the name of my provider.

```
provider: cloud-dns
```

Should have been:

```
provider: letsencrypt-prod
```